# SOQL query to find number of articles associated with a datacategory

Tags: apex, soql, knowledge, data-category

It seems that we cannot query data categories directly. I am trying to see which of my data categories I can delete because there are no articles attached to them.

Answer (score 1):

The [WITH DATA CATEGORY](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_with_datacategory.htm#:%7E:text=Apex-,WITH%20DATA%20CATEGORY%20filteringExpression,and%20are%20visible%20to%20users.) clause should solve your need. You just need to specify the top level data category and then the specific one you're interested in. The example from the docs is below

Assuming you have a Data Category setup like below

```
Geography__c
    usa__c
    canada__c
```

You could find all the articles with USA as a data category like so

```
SELECT Count() FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion WITH DATA CATEGORY Geography__c AT usa__c
```